# Solutions to 'make_dirs' problem in labelbox_json2yolo.py code

Tags: python, json, yolo, yolov5, yolov4

I'd like to convert my label file in *json to YOLO * txt with to class ('bsb','wsb') using the `labelbox_json2yolo.py` (https://github.com/ultralytics/JSON2YOLO/blob/master/labelbox_json2yolo.py) in Jupyter Notebook.

In my data (image and label file) I have:

```
file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/YT_EMBRAPA_002.zip" # Patch to zip file in GitHub

import json
import os
from pathlib import Path

import requests
import yaml
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm

from utils import make_dirs


def convert(file, zip=True):
    # Convert Labelbox JSON labels to YOLO labels
    names = ['bsb','wsb']  # class names
    file = Path(file)
    save_dir = make_dirs(file.stem)
    with open(file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)  # load JSON

    for img in tqdm(data, desc=f'Converting {file}'):
        im_path = img['Labeled Data']
        im = Image.open(requests.get(im_path, stream=True).raw if im_path.startswith('http') else im_path)  # open
        width, height = im.size  # image size
        label_path = save_dir / 'labels' / Path(img['External ID']).with_suffix('.txt').name
        image_path = save_dir / 'images' / img['External ID']
        im.save(image_path, quality=95, subsampling=0)

        for label in img['Label']['objects']:
            # box
            top, left, h, w = label['bbox'].values()  # top, left, height, width
            xywh = [(left + w / 2) / width, (top + h / 2) / height, w / width, h / height]  # xywh normalized

            # class
            cls = label['value']  # class name
            if cls not in names:
                names.append(cls)

            line = names.index(cls), *xywh  # YOLO format (class_index, xywh)
            with open(label_path, 'a') as f:
                f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')

    # Save dataset.yaml
    d = {'path': f"../datasets/{file.stem}  # dataset root dir",
         'train': "images/train  # train images (relative to path) 128 images",
         'val': "images/val  # val images (relative to path) 128 images",
         'test': " # test images (optional)",
         'nc': len(names),
         'names': names}  # dictionary

    with open(save_dir / file.with_suffix('.yaml').name, 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(d, f, sort_keys=False)

    # Zip
    if zip:
        print(f'Zipping as {save_dir}.zip...')
        os.system(f'zip -qr {save_dir}.zip {save_dir}')

    print('Conversion completed successfully!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert('export-2021-06-29T15_25_41.934Z.json')
```

Despite the corrected install of `utils`, when I have tried to run the script but I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 10
      7 from PIL import Image
      8 from tqdm import tqdm
---> 10 from utils import make_dirs

ImportError: cannot import name 'make_dirs' from 'utils' (C:\Users\fores\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)
```

Is possible to give a alternative way to local directory in my machine and not call `make_dirs(file.stem)`?
Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find `makedirs()` in `utils`.

I was able to find it in `os`, though:

```
from os import makedirs
```

Could it be that you are trying to look for it in the wrong package / module?

David

Comment: Thanks David and I try to find the wrong package. Your solution doesn't work too, for me. I have as output:  `----> 3 from os import make_dirs

ImportError: cannot import name 'make_dirs' from 'os' (C:\Users\fores\anaconda3\lib\os.py)`

Comment: Sorry... Typo on my part.  It's actually `from os import makedirs`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the rest of the [repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/JSON2YOLO/blob/master/labelbox_json2yolo.py), there is a utils.py which the `from utils import make_dirs` refers to.